# Atributo pattern en html5

Tags: html5

Estoy tratando de que un `input` reciba 8 números y una letra pero que al momento de que el usuario ingrese un valor de letra al principio no lo deje sino después de que haya ingresado 8 números. Lo estoy realizando con un `pattern` pero no me resulta. Sé que para validar un `input` numérico es de esta forma: `pattern="^[0-9]+"` pero no sé cómo implementar el formato mencionado anteriormente ni cómo debo indicarle al usuario que el primer dato que ingrese sea un número.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo que para ese tipo de mascaras, utilices un plugin llamado `JQUERY MASK`, es un plugin sencillo de utilizar, lee bien la documentacion, solo debes agregar el js antes de la etiqueta de cierre y despues de la etiqueta que llama a Jquery. Te dejo un ejemplo de su uso:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#texto1').mask('00000000A');
});
```

```html
<label>
    TITULO:
</label>
<input type="text" id="texto1">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js" integrity="sha512-pHVGpX7F/27yZ0ISY+VVjyULApbDlD0/X0rgGbTqCE7WFW5MezNTWG/dnhtbBuICzsd0WQPgpE4REBLv+UqChw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

---

> EXPLICACION DE FUNCIONAMIENTO

---

No se si haz utilizado Jquery pero es simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#texto1').mask('A#0#');
});
```

La primer y ultima linea son de Jquery, es de formato por lo que si quieres programar en ese lenguaje todo lo que pondras debe ir dentro, lo que esta en medio, hace el llamado al input (`$('#texto1')`) y con `.mask` le decimos que utilice la libreria que hemos colocado, para que tenga la funcion de mascara,

Lo que va dentro es el formato, con `00000000` le estamos diciendo que primero se aceptaran 8 numeros, si intentas escribir una letra no podra ser, y con `A`, le estamos diciendo que despues de los 8 numeros, se aceptara una letra, si deseas que se acepten mas de una letra pon n cantidad de `A` que necesites si es que es un formato especifico.

Pero si puede agregar las letras que quiera puedes usar `00000000#A#` asi le indicas que puede escribir despues de los 8 numeros, la cantidad de letras que desee.

Y asi puedes ir jugando con el formato, te dejo la documentacion para que veas mejor los ejemplos:

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html